# can't connect my Internet Service Provider ftp server

Tags: internet, remote, vsftpd

can't connect my isp ftp server. before that in windows 7 usually i can access my isp's ftp site. but in ubuntu it takes too long and at the end it shows "10.112.200.11/is not available". What can i do now? any kind of suggestion will be great. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What is the result of `traceroute 10.112.200.11`?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not your ISP's ftp server address (unless perhaps you are in their office), it's an IANA-reserved private IPv4 network range.

The suggestion: Contact your ISP and ask them for the outside IP address of their FTP server.

Note: My apologies if this shows up in the low quality answer queue.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address